# How to get final value from a for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, hash

I have a password like Abcd123 which I hashed by using shas256 at first and then added a salt with that hash and finally I used for loop to make a complicated password.My code looks as below :-

```
   $password = 'Abcd123';
   $salt = '1e841d1e9b09ae';
   $loop = hash('sha256', $password. $salt); 
   for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $loop = hash('sha256', $password. $salt); 
    } 
   echo $loop;
```

but now the problem is that guys no matter if I remove my whole for loop code

```
       for($round= 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $loop = hash('sha256,$password . $salt')
        }
```

or add that my echo $loop; produce the same result guys :( I mean it's like my for loop isn't doing its job! How can i solve that problem??

Comment: If you're hoping to repeatedly hash it over and over again, you need to change the line inside the loop to something like this: `$loop = hash('sha256', $loop. $salt);`. Note the $loop in the hash function instead of the original $password.

Comment: Regardless of the looping problem you've got, why are you bothering to rehash even once?  You are not gaining any practical improvement in protection.

Comment: Thanks for your guide @Octopoid bro.Ok I will keep it on mind.@Joseph bro I hash the hash value 65536 more times.The purpose of this was to protect against brute force attacks.Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning as a few others have - hashing a couple of times in a row might *arguably* have some merit, but hashing it tens of thousands of times will not improve your security, and frankly, is lunacy! If you want really solid protection against brute force attacks, just use extremely complicated salt.

Answer (score 3):

You are just repeating the same step over and over again, but without continuing on the previous results. You store the result in the variable `$loop`, but you don't *use* that variable as input for the next step.

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
$password = 'Abcd123';
$salt = '1e841d1e9b09ae';
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
{ 
    $password = hash('sha256', $password. $salt); 
} 
echo $password;
```

Note however, that it's probably way easier, less error-prone and therefore more secure to use PHP's built-in function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: You were right bro.Your code finally does for loop work :) Thanks for your help bro

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you might do some more debugging.  Have you tried just running this once:

```
$loop = hash('sha256,$password . $salt');
```

to see what happens?

Comment: yap bro I tried some thing like that so..I found this problem.But it worked now i followed @GolezTrol bro and solved my problem.